# Centering SKcamera on center of Y Axis

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skcameranode

Im trying to make my skcameranode be centered on the y axis of my scene. (Im using xcode and spritekit as game technology.

In swift the code would be : `cameranode.position.y = size.height / 2`
Any ideas how i can do this in objective c?

Comment: wouldn't it be the same in objective c

Comment: or really old school objective c `[[cameranode position] y] = [size height]/2`  (Yeah, this is why you should learn swift)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thanks for answering ! But [[cameranode position] y] = [size height]/2 didnt seem to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: yeah, explain your question better. Dot notation works, so the code you provided works in objective c, you only need to use brackets when calling methods

Comment: I am going to say whatever "cameranode" is, is incorrect

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I actually just found a working way ! But thanks for helping ! cheers.